# CS0429 - Unreachable expression code detected with MSBuild 4, but not 14

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn

The following sample of code demonstrates a difference I'm seeing between Visual Studio 2012 and 2015 (MSBuild 4 and 14). It's based on the description found in this article:

[Compiler Warning (level 4) CS0429](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ch1a3w5.aspx)

```
namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    using System;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test_CS0429()
        {
            if (false && ReturnTrue())  // CS0429  
            {
                Assert.Fail();
            }
        }

        static bool ReturnTrue(){return true;}
    }
}
```

When I compile this using MSBuild 4 I correctly get the warning CS0429, yet when I compile the same code in MSBuild 14 I don't get the warning. The behavior is repeatable in Visual Studio.

The specific versions of MSBuild I'm using are 4.6.1055.0 and 14.0.25420.1.

Can anyone explain this difference, I would like/expect the warnings to be consistent between versions?

What may be relevant is the versions of csc.exe in play

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe version 1.3.1.60616

Compared with:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe version 4.6.1055.0

Comment: Interesting, out of curiosity is there a difference if the unit test is static as per msdn?

Comment: @JeremyThompson no the results are the same, I was just getting some other resharper warnings with the code from msdn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug that previous versions of the C# compiler reported this diagnostic. It was the result of a compiler engineer over generalizing the requirements of the language specification. See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16147

The C# language specification requires compilers to produce a warning for unreachable statements. However, the C# language does not have a concept of "reachable expression". Reachability is carefully defined by the language specification, but it is a concept that applies only to statements, not to expressions. Newer compilers will no longer report this error, and we have no plans to reintroduce it.

Comment: Thanks Neal, this is a shame as I found the warning rather useful.